# How to subclass a templated base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

I have the following data structures:

```
struct fastEngine { ... }
struct slowEngine { ... }

template<typename T>
class Car {
   T engine;
   vector<T> backupEngines;

   virtual void drive() = 0;
}

class FastCar : public Car<fastEngine> {
   virtual void drive() {
      // use the values of "engine" in some way
   }
}

class SlowCar : public Car<slowEngine> {
   virtual void drive() {
      // use the values of "engine" in some way
   }
}

Car* getCarFromCarFactory() {  // 1
   if (randomNumber == 0)
      return new FastCar();
   else
      return new SlowCar();
}

void main() {
   Car* myCar = getCarFromCarFactory(); // 2
   myCar->drive();
}
```

The compiler complains at locations 1 and 2 because it requires that I define **Car*** with template parameters. I don't care what templated version of **Car** I'm using, I just want a pointer to a **Car** that I can drive. The **engine** structs must be structs because they are from existing code and I don't have control over them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create a non-templated base class that `Car<T>` inherits, e.g.

```
struct ICar {
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Car : public ICar {
    // ...
}

int main() { // BTW, it's always `int main`, not `void main`
    ICar *myCar = getCarFromCarFactory();
    myCar->drive();
}
```

Comment: It's ugly being forced to have another interface, but it works. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Brian: The whole point of the interface is to minimize the exposed  surface area of the class (i.e. encapsulating away the templating).  Since it doesn't look like you need to know the type of the engine in the class using the car, it is more clean to hide that information.

Comment: If you're going to throw int main opinions into your answer, at least add a return statement! I seriously can't comprehend people that force others to use int main but are fine letting the compiler infer a return value.

Comment: @codetaku It's not "an opinion", it's required by the standard (unlike return in it, which explicitly defaults to return 0).

Comment: @codetaku What if I told you that `return 0;` in `main` is optional in C++, and `int main()` is required?

Comment: @codetaku `int main` is required by the standard. The fact that `void main` compiles at all in the OP's case is, IMO, a deficiency of the compiler.

Comment: @Brian: It's not "ugly"; it's elegant. You've misunderstood the extent to which your existing class template `Car` actually provides _any_ interface.

Answer (score 5):

PiotrLegnica's answer is right, but I'd just like to add a few points:

### class templates are not classes

In your code, Car is a class template. A class template is *not* a class, it is only ... a template from which classes can be defined, and different instantiations of a same template do not necessarily lead to types having the same interface. A simple example:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  T Bar();
  bool Baz(const T&);
};
```

### struct and class is (almost) the same thing

> The engine structs must be structs
>   because they are from existing code
>   and I don't have control over them.

I assume that you wrote this because you were suspecting that the problem was related to the use of structs instead of classes as template parameters. This is not the case. In C++, struct and class is almost the same thing. The only difference is that the default access and inheritance are public with a struct while they are private with a class.